# Getting null Records while reading multiple records in Aerospike

Tags: aerospike

I have a **namespace**: **test** and **set**: **user** in Aerospike database. I add four records in users through the following command on console:

```
ascli put test users barberakey '{"username":"Barbera","password":"barbera","gender":"f","region":"west","company":"Audi"}'
```

Through aql command, I can view these four records.
 aql> select * from test.users.

I know the method to get records one by one and it runs fine at my side, but it is very expensive operation for my task.I want to read multiple records(batch read) and to perform multiple algorithms on them. I took guidance from https://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/java/usage/kvs/batch.html and write code as followed:

Key[] keys = new Key[4];

```
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    keys[i] = new Key("test", "users", (i + 1));
                    System.out.println("Keys: "+keys[i]);
                }

                Record[] records = client.get(batchPolicy, keys);
                System.out.println("Length of Records : "+records.length);
                for(int a=0;a<records.length;a++){
                  System.out.println("RECORDS IN ARRAY: "+records[a]);

                }
```

But, the problem is that it reads keys but giving Array records null.

```
Output:
Reading records from Aerospike DB
Keys: test:users:1:3921e84015258aed3b93d7ef5770cd27b9bb4167
Keys: test:users:2:1effb3ce25b23f92c5371dee0ac8e6b34f5703c6
Keys: test:users:3:d17519d72e22beab2c3fa1552910ea3380c262bd
Keys: test:users:4:3f09a505c913db8ad1118e20b78c5bb8495fb0f9
Length of Records : 4
RECORDS IN ARRAY: null
RECORDS IN ARRAY: null
RECORDS IN ARRAY: null
RECORDS IN ARRAY: null
```

Please guide me for the case.

......

Comment: Are/were there any migrations when you ran this? Could you provide the output of `asadm -e info`?

Comment: During migrations, batch request may not return all of the values; the current batch implementation does not proxy requests within the batch. The upcoming 3.6.x release will include a new batch operation which is run at a higher priority and will proxy if the records could exist on another node.

Comment: Do you have any idea that how can I achieve my purpose? Actually I am getting records and then save into an arrayList and then apply operations on it. I want to avoid writing in arrayList and want to do operations directly on records.

Answer (score 2):

Appears you wrote the records using the key "barberakey".  Then read the records by an integer key "i+1". Thus, the records are not found.

Comment: Yes I already solved the problem. Anyway thank you for the message.